# Change color of entire page

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, styling, react-bootstrap

I have a button which creates a popup and makes the background of my page black. This works however it doesn't affect any bootstrap containers. I am currently using bootstrap 4 and react. [image]

My css for this pop is below

```
.popup {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.5) !important;
}
.popupInner {
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 25%;
    right: 25%;
    top: 25%;
    bottom: 25%;
    margin: auto;
    background: white;
}
```

Anyone have any insight on how to target these containers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a z-index on popup will probably fix it (e.g. `z-index: 1`).

If that doesn't fix it, you may need to set a lower z-index on those bootstrap elements (e.g. `z-index: 0`)

Comment: That fixed it. Gave the .popup a z-index:100 and popupInner a z-index : 101